# How to force interpreter show complete stack trace?

Tags: scala, interpreter, sbt

Is there any way to force Scala interpreter (started through SBT) to print complete stack trace. By default, less than 10 lines are displayed:

```
scala> new CacheMonitoringClient
javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: com.bea:Name=DomainRuntimeService,Type=weblogic.management.beanservers.domainrun
time.DomainRuntimeServiceMBean
        at weblogic.rjvm.ResponseImpl.unmarshalReturn(ResponseImpl.java:195)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicRemoteRef.invoke(BasicRemoteRef.java:224)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl_921_WLStub.getAttribute(Unknown Source)
        at weblogic.management.remote.common.RMIConnectionWrapper$11.run(ClientProviderBase.java:498)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:147)
        at weblogic.security.Security.runAs(Security.java:61)
        at weblogic.management.remote.common.RMIConnectionWrapper.getAttribute(ClientProviderBas...
```

As a workaround I'm using `try { new CacheMonitoringClient } catch { case ex => ex.printStackTrace}` (explicitly wrapping the calls that throw the exceptions I'm interested in),  but that really ugly...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `lastException` if you want just one thing:

```
scala> 1 / 0
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at .<init>(<console>:12)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at RequestResult$.<init>(<console>:9)
    at RequestResult$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at RequestResult$scala_repl_result(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter$Request$$anonfun$loadAndRun$1$$anonfun$apply$18.apply(Interpreter.scala:981)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter$Request$$anonfun$loadAndRun$1$$anonfun$apply$18.apply(Interpreter.scala:981)
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:79)
    at scal...
scala> lastException.printStackTrace
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at line101$object$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$.<init>(<console>:12)
    at line101$object$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at RequestResult$line101$object$.<init>(<console>:9)
    at RequestResult$line101$object$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at RequestResult$line101$object.scala_repl_result(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter$Request$$anonfun$loadAndRun$1$$anonfun$apply$18.apply(Interpreter.scala:981)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter$Request$$anonfun$loadAndRun$1$$anonfun$apply$18.apply(Interpreter.scala:981)
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:79)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter$Request$$anonfun$loadAndRun$1.apply(Interpreter.scala:980)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter$Request$$anonfun$loadAndRun$1.apply(Interpreter.scala:980)
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:79)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter$Request.loadAndRun(Interpreter.scala:979)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter.loadAndRunReq$1(Interpreter.scala:578)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.scala:597)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.scala:575)
    at scala.tools.nsc.InterpreterLoop.reallyInterpret$1(InterpreterLoop.scala:471)
    at scala.tools.nsc.InterpreterLoop.interpretStartingWith(InterpreterLoop.scala:514)
    at scala.tools.nsc.InterpreterLoop.command(InterpreterLoop.scala:361)
    at scala.tools.nsc.InterpreterLoop.processLine$1(InterpreterLoop.scala:242)
    at scala.tools.nsc.InterpreterLoop.repl(InterpreterLoop.scala:248)
    at scala.tools.nsc.InterpreterLoop.main(InterpreterLoop.scala:558)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:72)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

Or set `settings.maxPrintString` to 0, though that will change how normal results are printed too.

```
scala> settings.maxPrintString = 0

scala> 1 /0
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at .<init>(<console>:12)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at RequestResult$.<init>(<console>:9)
    at RequestResult$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at RequestResult$scala_repl_result(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter$Request$$anonfun$loadAndRun$1$$anonfun$apply$18.apply(Interpreter.scala:981)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter$Request$$anonfun$loadAndRun$1$$anonfun$apply$18.apply(Interpreter.scala:981)
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:79)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter$Request$$anonfun$loadAndRun$1.apply(Interpreter.scala:980)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter$Request$$anonfun$loadAndRun$1.apply(Interpreter.scala:980)
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:79)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter$Request.loadAndRun(Interpreter.scala:979)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter.loadAndRunReq$1(Interpreter.scala:578)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.scala:597)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.scala:575)
    at scala.tools.nsc.InterpreterLoop.reallyInterpret$1(InterpreterLoop.scala:471)
    at scala.tools.nsc.InterpreterLoop.interpretStartingWith(InterpreterLoop.scala:514)
    at scala.tools.nsc.InterpreterLoop.command(InterpreterLoop.scala:361)
    at scala.tools.nsc.InterpreterLoop.processLine$1(InterpreterLoop.scala:242)
    at scala.tools.nsc.InterpreterLoop.repl(InterpreterLoop.scala:248)
    at scala.tools.nsc.InterpreterLoop.main(InterpreterLoop.scala:558)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:72)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

Comment: @Missing Keep paying attention to paulp on mailing lists and irc, and he will sometimes show off some new trick he implemented. Other than that, just press `<TAB>` and see what's there, see what methods are implemented, go to power mode and repeat, etc.

Comment: For more recent versions of Scala 2.x, you cannot use `settings.maxPrintString`, instead see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516567/settings-maxprintstring-for-scala-2-9-repl

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
trace on
```

in SBT before entering the console? On is the default, but perhaps it is being overwritten in your case.

Comment: Tried against SBT 0.7.4. No difference with trace on/off - in the both cases, stack trace is displayed and cut.

Comment: Yes, just tried it myself (had to install first). Also tried the trace <integer> option but there's no difference. Sorry for the red herring.

Comment: I note that the REPL will also truncate exceptions outside of an SBT context, so it may not be SBT doing this.