# settings.maxPrintString for Scala 2.9 REPL

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

I'd like to disable truncation of string values in the Scala REPL.

The following thread suggested typing `settings.maxPrintString = 0`:

[How to force interpreter show complete stack trace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767808/how-to-force-interpreter-show-complete-stack-trace/3769827#3769827)

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work with Scala 2.9:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.1.final (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_29).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> settings.maxPrintString = 0
<console>:10: error: not found: value settings
val $ires0 = settings.maxPrintString
             ^
<console>:7: error: not found: value settings
       settings.maxPrintString = 0
       ^
```

Is there something I need to import?

I tried `:power`, which makes `settings` available, but it doesn't seem to support `maxPrintString`:

```
scala> :power
** Power User mode enabled - BEEP BOOP SPIZ **
** :phase has been set to 'typer'.          **
** scala.tools.nsc._ has been imported      **
** global._ and definitions._ also imported **
** Try  :help,  vals.<tab>,  power.<tab>    **

scala> settings
res0: scala.tools.nsc.Settings = 
Settings {
  -d = .
  -Yrich-exceptions = true
  -classpath = bin:lib/*
  -encoding = UTF-8
}


scala> settings.maxPrintString = 0
<console>:31: error: value maxPrintString is not a member of scala.tools.nsc.Settings
val $ires9 = settings.maxPrintString
                      ^
<console>:28: error: value maxPrintString is not a member of scala.tools.nsc.Settings
       settings.maxPrintString = 0
```

I see that `scala.tools.nsc.InterpreterSettings.maxPrintString` exists, but I'm not sure how to get an appropriate instance of `InterpreterSettings` to modify.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
  ~/code/scala scala29
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.1.final (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_29).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> :power
** Power User mode enabled - BEEP BOOP SPIZ **
** :phase has been set to 'typer'.          **
** scala.tools.nsc._ has been imported      **
** global._ and definitions._ also imported **
** Try  :help,  vals.<tab>,  power.<tab>    **

    scala> vals.isettings.maxPrintString
maxPrintString     maxPrintString_=   

scala> vals.isettings.maxPrintString = 10000
vals.isettings.maxPrintString: Int = 10000
```

or

```
$ scala -uniqid -Xprint:typer -Yshow-syms -Dscala.repl.maxprintstring=64000
```

where the sample output will show truncation without the higher limit.

Comment: Thanks retronym! I should have tried what it said to try!  I see that setting 0 now seems to really mean zero.  Is there any way to set unlimited these days, or do you just have to choose a large number, as you've done above (I tried -1, but no luck)

Comment: Never mind.  Int.MaxValue will be fine, and with the nice Ctrl-R support, I won't actually have to type it very often.  Or I can just use -i, with the -Yrepl-sync workaround so it doesn't hang.

Comment: Works in Scala 2.10.3 too :)