# Scala: How to print all values in a long vector without ellipsis

Tags: scala

I'd like to print all values of a vector which has about 700 elements. By default, a relatively small number (maybe 100 or so) are printed, and then an ellipsis (...). Is there a way to print all the values?

Of course, I could go through the elements one by one, but I'm hoping to avoid that.

EDIT: I am printing stuff via println. Unless I've misunderstood something, changing maxPrintString doesn't seem to affect println output (or toString, since I suppose println must be calling toString).

Comment: are you talking about the REPL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [settings.maxPrintString for Scala 2.9 REPL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516567/settings-maxprintstring-for-scala-2-9-repl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using scala's REPL, it will print out the value of whatever expression you type in, but if the `toString` of that value would be unreasonably long, it truncates it and adds `...`.

If you want the whole thing, you just need to explicily print it. Use `println`.

```
scala> val  list = List.fill(700)('a')
list: List[Char] = List(a, a, /*omitting some for brevity*/, a, ...

scala> println(list)
// it actually prints everything

// or you could print individual elements
scala> list foreach println
```

Comment: Thanks, println works as you point out. I don't know why I didn't see that before, I thought I tried several things and couldn't make it work. Anyway thanks for putting me on the right track.