# Scala REPL truncates the output

Tags: scala, environment-variables, truncate, scala-repl

I would like to know if is there any way to avoid that Scala REPL truncates the output by setting a environment variable or whatever?

Example

```
scala> typeOf[Iterator[_]].members.mkString("\n")
res6: String =
override def toString(): String
def toStream: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[A]
def toIterator: Iterator[A]
def toTraversable: Traversable[A]
def sameElements: <?>
def copyToArray[B >: A](xs: Array[B],start: Int,len: Int): Unit
def patch: <?>
def duplicate: <?>
def length: <?>
def sliding$default$2: <?>
def sliding: <?>
def grouped: <?>
class GroupedIterator extends
def buffered: <?>
def indexOf: <?>
def indexOf: <?>
def indexWhere: <?>
def indexWhere: <?>
def find(p: A => Boolean): Option[A]
def contains: <?>
def exists(p: A => Boolean): Boolean
...
```

I would like to see all the content.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/434a3d78fa1ec160ab090bc434bccbfc684a07d0/src/repl-frontend/scala/tools/nsc/interpreter/shell/Reporter.scala#L95) and [retronym](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9524003/5205022)

```
  /** The maximum length of toString to use when printing the result
    *  of an evaluation.  0 means no maximum.  If a printout requires
    *  more than this number of characters, then the printout is
    *  truncated.
    */
  var maxPrintString = config.maxPrintString.option getOrElse 800
```

where

```
val maxPrintString = int("scala.repl.maxprintstring")
```

hence start REPL like so

```
scala -Dscala.repl.maxprintstring=0
```

to have no truncation.

---

Addressing the comment, `intp.isettings` seems to have been removed in Scala 2.13 by [REPL: decouple the UI (shell) from the compiler [ci: last-only] #5903](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/5903). There exists [TODO](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/914a270fc3f1a6aea5684426ec74a19dfb23ee72/src/repl/scala/tools/nsc/interpreter/ReplVals.scala#L27) which states:

```
  // TODO bring back access to shell features from the interpreter?
  // The repl backend has now cut its ties to the shell, except for the ReplReporter interface
  // Before, we gave the user access to: repl, reader, isettings (poor name), completion and history.
  // We could bring back some of this functionality if desired by adding it to ReplReporter
```

hence in Scala 2.13 use `-Dscala.repl.maxprintstring` approach, however setting in from inside REPL should work pre-2.13

```
scala> $intp.isettings.maxPrintString = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, so I can do => scala> :power   , and then => vals.isettings.maxPrintString = Int.MaxValue,    vals.isettings.maxPrintString: Int = 2147483647. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround is to print the string directly:

```
println(res6)
```