# How do I get Scala to show the full error stack trace?

Tags: scala, debugging, stack-trace

I am trying to understand an error I'm getting when running a Scala program. However, the error is always elided for readability and I am not able to debug my problem. How do I get the full stack trace?

Example error:

> java.lang.AbstractMethodError   at
>   com.cibo.scalastan.ScalaStan$StanCode$class.$init$(ScalaStan.scala:146)
>   ... 57 elided

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3769827/2928853 . Use `lastException.printStackTrace`

Comment: That did it - thank you!